# Cupertino Icons not showing on android device

Tags: android, flutter, icons, cupertinopicker, cupertino-widgets

I'm new to flutter, and I'm trying to use CupertinoDatePicker and CupertinoPicker on an android app, on Android Studio emulator(Android 10 and 11) it's showing normally and on a Galaxy M21s(Android 11) too.

The problem is when I try to run it on my own phone, a Moto G8 Plus (Android 10) and some other devices the cupertino icons does not appear on screen. [print from Moto G8 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM92A.jpg)

Using the Moto G8 Plus to debug, I could see that Cupertino Icons are there receiving commands and printing it on console, they are just not visible.

What may be the problem? Or it's just a bug...

Answer (score 0):

It was the dumbest reason possible, `CupertinoDatePicker` and `CupertinoPicker` were setting the text to white in some devices for some reason that I don't know.

So, simple solution, I just changed text color.